# xampp is not working and i try almost every thing

Tags: xampp, mysql-workbench

i downloaded MySQL workbench and the port is 3306 then i runs the x.a.m.p.p and the port is 3306 also i change the x.a.m.p.p port to 3307 and still not working 
is their any solution to this

Comment: No there is not unless you provide more deails (:

Answer (score 0):

First we need to make sure that you installed XAMPP in proper way. Follow this video about [how to prepare PHP environment using XAMPP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9hbSL4ctMw).
If you followed the steps correctly make sure that both MySQL and Apache servers are running.

Then in XAMPP control panel click on MYSQL Admin. It will open phpMyAdmin and it will show a successful connection to MySQL server. If you noticed any error this means you have problem in your MySQL server.

Also it will be a good help to tell us from there your server type and version and your MySQL workbench version.